# No Exported Member / Node Modules

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I am just starting Angular 2 / Typescript using the 5 Minute Quickstart found [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html).  I've run into what looks to be a common problem, but maybe a bit different.  I am encountering all sorts of "No Exported Member" problems.  Examples:

From app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Returns

```
...node_modules/@angular2/core/index" has no exported member 'NgModule'.
```

and

```
...@angular/platform-browser/index" has no exported member 'BrowserModule'.
```

And from main.ts:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
```

throws:

```
...@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index" has no exported member 'platformBrowserDynamic'.
```

I am running node version 4.4.7 and npm version 3.10.5.

I understand that these are probably resolvable in the context of the tutorial by rolling back node or npm to version relevant to the tutorial.  I guess what I would prefer to have is an explanation of how to make the code from the tutorial relevant to the current versions of node.

ETA:  These errors occur at compilation, not execution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `NgModule` class is exported from the `node_modules/@angular/core/src/metadata.d.ts` file through the `node_modules/@angular/core/index.d.ts` one.

I wonder if you specify correctly the `moduleResolution` property in your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node", // <-----
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

Comment: The resolution is exactly that.  Admittedly I hand type every file of a tutorial just to get used to the syntax, but once I get compilation errors the first thing I do is go back and replace my hand typed work with a direct copy / paste from the source.  In this case what you posted is exactly the contents of my tsconfig.json

Comment: Perhaps I am being too literal, but there is no export of NgModule in either my metadata.d.ts or index.d.ts file.  In fact, 'NgModule' does not appear at all in either file.

Comment: Really! Which version of Angular2 do you use because it appears from RC5... Have a look at your `package.json` file.

Comment: 2.0.0-rc.4.  And that is directly from the linked source code

Comment: I will change that in my package.json and see if that fixes the issues.

Comment: Though isn't it odd that they would call for rc.4 in the tutorial and then call imports that don't exist in rc.4?

Answer (score 61):

For me it was VSCode editor issue. Simply reopening the editor resolved it

Comment: That's exactly the same issue with Atom. I didn't even need to close it, just erased and typed again, and no more ts error.

Comment: FWIW, I think there's a reload feature in both editors (Cmd + Shift + P, Developer: Reload Window in VSCode, probably similar in Atom) that also fixes this issue without having to close / reopen

Answer (score 4):

please update all your @angular dependencies in package.json to at least "2.0.0-rc.5"

after that verify your application bootstrap in main.ts.

according to changelog of 2.0.0-rc.5 there is a change of bootstrap your app. or see also updated tutorial guide https://angular.io/guide/quickstart.

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: […], // directives, components, and pipes owned by this NgModule
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  providers: […], // additional providers
  bootstrap: [MainComponent],
})
class MyAppModule {}

// Ahead of Time compile
import {platformBrowser} from ‘@angular/platform-browser’;

platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(MyAppModuleNgFactory);

// JIT compile long form
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from ‘@angular/platform-browser-dynamic’;

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(MyAppModule);
```

Answer (score 1):

Editor cache issue, its common in IDE's Android Studio,VS Code & Atom.
Restarting the editor/IDE will help.

Answer (score 0):

In package.json file, all dependencies which are using rc.4, replace them by rc.5. Then it will work.