# Modules with Angular 2 CLI

Tags: javascript, angular, module, command-line-interface

I'm ramping up on Angular 2 and have created my project using Angular 2 CLI's

```
ng new <my project name>
```

However, I noticed that this project doesn't include an app.module.ts file by default.

When I try creating my own file and setting it up with my default settings

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule   
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I get a build error saying

> ... @angular/core has no exported member 'NgModule'.

Any ideas on how to get the module file to work with Angular CLI?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be due to reasons please make sure

- please update all your @angular dependencies in package.json to at least "2.0.0-rc.5"
- check this property in tsconfig.json file

  > moduleResolution": "node", // <-----

like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38900745/5043867

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work.
Another option is running npm install -g angular-cli@webpack which will automatically create the module file